# Trying to understand Mongoose save() method

Tags: javascript, mongoose, es6-promise

Reading the docs I see;

> Mongoose async operations, like .save() and queries, return ES6 promises.

Thought I was familiar with ES6 promises, so I wrote something like this:

```
          newUser.save().then(user =>
            res.json({
              id: user.id,
              name: user.name,
              email: user.email
            })
          )
          .catch(
            (err = res.status(500).json({
              server: 'Something went wrong, please try again soon'
            }))
          );
```

I test and find a successful append to the DB, however a 500 gets called anyways. The error logged goes like this:

```
(node:40071) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

With a stack trace, moreover:

```
(node:40071) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:40071) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I'm scratching my head and consult with the specs, [Promise docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

And I'm puzzled as to why this throws errors, because I thought I am very clearly handling errors. Moreover, all errors just seem to vanish when I remove the catch statement all together! Like what is going on?

Comment: I think this line here is pretty suspect: `.catch((err = res.status(500).json({`

Comment: In case you didn't grasp what that meant `err => res.status...` See the `=>` as compared to `=`

Comment: Wow :| Yehp, well that solved all my problems.